# WPF Popup Location Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, popup, popupwindow

My application has one `Main Window`. and `Main Window` has one button. [Looks Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxm8Q.png)  When User Click that button, pop out `Setting Window`. I want to put it on the right side of `Main Window`. Even when the user is moving while holding the `Main Window`. At first time, i tried it in xaml code of `Setting Window`.
[It made me happy for a few minutes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or3jr.png) but it worked differently than I imagined.
After all, what I want is a `Setting Window` located on the right side of the `Main Window`. Wherever the `Main Window` is, it sticks to the right side of the `Main Window`, and even if you drag it out, you want the Main Window and `Setting Window` to move together.

**View Model**

```
public ICommand CheckCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_CheckCommand == null)
                {
                    _CheckCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>(Check);
                }

                return _CheckCommand;
            }
        }

        private void Check(bool state)
        {
            OutputView outputView = new OutputView();
            if (state)
            {
                Uri = new Uri("..\\Resources\\openiconReverse.png", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                Uri = new Uri("..\\Resources\\openicon.png", UriKind.Relative);

                foreach (Window item in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<OutputView>())
                {
                    item.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2">
            <ToggleButton Height="405" Width="30" 
                          Margin="0 -1.1 0 0" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          x:Name="OpenOutput" 
                          Command="{Binding CheckCommand}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
                
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Name="openicon" Source="{Binding Uri}"
                               Margin="0 0 2 15"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToggleButton>
        </Grid>
```

```
`Title="OutputView" Height="474" Width="346" WindowStyle="None"
        Left="1409" Top="296"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"`
```

I tried to adjust the position using the `left` and `top` attributes.

Comment: Control handling, UI logic and UI resource management does not belong inside the view model. The use of `Application.Current` is a good indicator that you are creating a code smell. Even worse, when implementing the MVVM pattern you would break it. The code you have shown (`Check()`) completely belongs to the code-behind of the control that hosts the `ToggleButton` (for example `MainWindow`) - the view.

Comment: As the name `"OutputView"` already implies is `OutputView` a type of the View component. A simple `Button.Click` handler or alternatively `ToggleButton.Checked` and `ToggleButton.Unchecked` event handler will do it. Class names are a good cue to know to which application component a class reference belongs to. When it ends with ...View or ...Element than it belongs to the View i.e. is only referenced in the View.

Comment: If you keep a reference to each opened Window e.g. in a `List<Window` you have direct access to the correct instances. This avoids the static reference to Application.Current and also improves the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the `Popup.HorizontalOffset` or `Popup.VerticalOffset` property value the `Popup` will automatically reposition itself relative to the new `Popup.PlacementTarget` location.

The following example creates a `Popup` that is located outside to the right of the application window and that will update the position when the window is being resized or moved:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Name="MainWindowControl">
  <StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="PopupExpander" 
                  Content="Show Popup attached to the right side of MainWindow" />
    <Popup x:Name="StickyPopup" 
           IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PopupExpander, Path=IsChecked}" 
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowControl}" 
           Placement="Right">
      <Grid Background="White" MinHeight="100">
        <TextBlock Text="Some content" />
      </Grid>
    </Popup>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnLocationChanged(e);
    TriggerPopupPositionUpdate(this.StickyPopup);
  }

  protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
  {
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    TriggerPopupPositionUpdate(this.StickyPopup);
  }

  private void TriggerPopupPositionUpdate(Popup popup)
  {
    popup.HorizontalOffset += 1;
    popup.HorizontalOffset -= 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Popup control for these things. You can use it like this:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleButtonOpen}" LostFocus="ToggleButton_LostFocus">
    <Popup x:Name="ToggleButton" IsOpen="{Binding IsToggleButtonOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton}" Placement="Bottom">
        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="290" CornerRadius="0 12 12 12" Background="White">
                <DockPanel>
                                    
                </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</ToggleButton>
```

This can be controlled by changing the IsToggleButtonOpen property (I have not tested this code). You can implement the LostFocus if you want to close the popup when the user click on something else (the implementation is trivial, something like IsToggleButtonOpen=false;)

If you also want the popup to move when you move the window, you have to override the LocationChanged event of the window. You have to make the popup snap in place, so you just need to change the HorizontalOffset and change it back:

```
private void MovePopup()
{
     var offset = UserProfilePopup.HorizontalOffset;
     UserProfilePopup.HorizontalOffset = offset + 1;
     UserProfilePopup.HorizontalOffset = offset;
}
```

Note that you might need to override also the behaviour when you maximize the window.